# EntityQuery OrderBy additional filtering. WCF Ria

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, ria

I've got this code to create entityQuery for loading my entities:

```
if (filterExpresion != null)
{
    riaQuery = riaQuery.Where(
        Expression.Lambda(
            filterExpresion,
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "item") // NOI18N
            ) as Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>
        );
}

if (OrderBy != null)
{
    var orderByExpression = 
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int>>(
            OrderBy, 
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "item")
        );

    riaQuery.OrderBy(orderByExpression);
}
```

so.. Where clause is setted and i can see it in Query-property of riaQuery, but i can't see any OrderBy clause and i have no orderby-filtering in this query.

```
riaQuery.IsComposable == true
```

Why OrderBy do not appliyng to Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy *returns* the resulting `IOrderedQueryable`.  change to:

```
riaQuery = riaQuery.OrderBy(orderByExpression);
```